# PHP reproduce exact working sql query but no result

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
-- GET INVITES
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pda.get_invite;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pda.get_invite ( code varchar(100), invitator_id bigint )
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM pda_invites
WHERE (pda_invites.invitator_id = invitator_id || invitator_id IS NULL)
AND (pda_invites.code = code || code IS NULL);
END //

CALL get_invite ( 'cec95191-23db-11e9-86d7-26374278e97f', NULL );
```

That works in phpmyadmin and deliver the desired result.

Now on php side, I've got some kind of query builder in a procedure class with registered arguments, which looks like this:

```
public function toSQL ( ) {

    // Make sure params are set
    if ( $this->ready == false ) {
        throw new Exception ( 'Called unready procedure  ' . $this->PROCEDURE_NAME . '.' );
        return false;
    }

    // Build query
    $sql= 'CALL ' . $this->PROCEDURE_NAME . '( ';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $this->args as $arg ) {
        $param = $this->params[ $i ][ $arg['NAME'] ];

        // Apply valid null values
        if ( $param == null || $param == 'null' ) {
            $sql = $sql . 'NULL';

        // Apply varchar strings
        } else if ( $arg['TYPE'] == 'varchar' ) {
            $sql = $sql . '\'' . $param . '\'';

        // Apply numeric values
        }  else {
            $sql = $sql . $param;
        }      

        if ( ($i+1) < $this->args_count ) {
            $sql = $sql . ', ';
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $sql = $sql . ' );';

    return $sql;
}
```

In my DB Service I trigger that by calling:

```
$sql = $procedure->toSQL();    
$result = $con->query($sql);
echo($sql);
echo json_encode($result);
```

That results in following equivalent query string which is also reflected by the mysql log:

```
CALL get_invite( 'cec95191-23db-11e9-86d7-26374278e97f', NULL );
```

But the problem and question is that it produces an empty result:

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

Have anyone a clue why it coulds behave this way?

Comment: You might get a better response if you edit your post and remove the "hurry" part.  [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: You've wasted time doing a stored procedure builder rather than a simpler piece of PHP based SQL code that could of been easily verified. The lack of `$this->args` make it hard to follow too. You're also forming SQL queries with string concatenation which is going to lead to SQL injection eventually. Forget about stored procedures and use simple code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I know that string builder is more of a straight forward solution, will definetly change to PDO with prepared statements. But why should I forget about stored procedures at all? I kind of fixed the above problem b y copying row by row with json_encode / json_decode in the fetch_assoc while loop ... still searching for a better solution

Comment: concatenate $sql .= $sql . 'NULL';    and check